# jQuery animate function not working for display and -webkit-transform property

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is working for all attribute except display and -webkit-transform   attribute.

```
// Example 1 :

$(this).animate({
               "color":"#efbe5c",
               "display":"block"
},1000);


 // Example 2 :

$(this).animate({
              "-webkit-transform":"rotate(30deg)"
},1000);
```

Comment: on which event u want to animate

Comment: Are you trying to fade in/out?  You should play with `opacity` instead.  Animating display doesn't really make sense because it doesn't make sense to animate between `inline` and `block`, for example.

Comment: How do you animate display? Are you sure you should'nt be animating the opacity ?

Comment: @jmar777 : I used fadeIn / fadeOut for display.It works. But for     "-webkit-transform" why animate not working. Any Idea ?

Comment: @ShivajiRanaware Because jQuery can't handle non-numeric animations (i.e., it doesn't know what to do with `rotate(30deg)`.  There may be a plugin for that, or you can update the property manually using the `step` callback.

Comment: @ShivajiRanaware I just posted an answer below with a jsfiddle to illustrate.

Answer (score 3):

From [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)s documentation:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; **most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality** (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

However, `opacity` would fade to the given value.

jQuery has an example of this on their [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) page under "Basic Usage" to animate any element, such as a simple image:

**HTML**

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123"
  style="position: relative; left: 10px;" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

You are also able to set a `toggle` value to the `opacity` like so:

```
$( "p" ).animate({
  height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"
}, "slow" );
```

Answer (score 3):

You should animate the opacity property of the element instead of it's display type.

first set it's css to `display:block` and `opacity:0` to make it invisible, and then animate it's opacity property to `opacity:1`.

```
$(this).css({"display":"block","opacity":0})animate({"opacity":"1"},1000);
```

Also colors cannot be animated without an external jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property. The only required parameter is a plain object of CSS properties. This object is similar to the one that can be sent to the .css() method, except that the range of properties is more restrictive.

```
$("#block").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
    }, 1500 );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CmgH9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can put your code like this:

```
    $(this).animate({
                   "color":"#efbe5c"                   
    },1000).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to Use opacity

```
$(this).animate({
           "color":"#efbe5c",
           "opacity":"1",},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example animating the `opacity` and the `-webkit-transform`.

Note that we're using the `step` callback for the `-webkit-transform`, since jQuery doesn't know how to animate `rotate(30deg)` out of the box:

```
var $test = $('#test');
$test.animate({
    opacity: 1
}, {
    step: function(now, fx) {
        $test.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + (30 * now) + 'deg)');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CBWjh/